# Get the Sum of the Values of Letters in a Name

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Numerologists claim to be able to determine a person's character traits based on the "numeric value" of a name. The value of a name is determined by summing up the values of the letters of the name. For example, the name *Zelle* would have the value 26 + 5 + 12 + 12 + 5 = 60. Write a function called `get_numeric_value` that takes a sequence of characters (a string) as a parameter. It should return the numeric value of that string. You can use `to_numerical` in your solution.**

First, my code for `to_numerical` (a function I had to make to convert letters to numbers [notably not the ASCII codes; had to start from A = 1, etc.]) was this:

```
def to_numerical(character): 
    if character.isupper():
        return ord(character) - 64
    elif character.islower():
        return ord(character) - 96
```

In regards to the actual problem, I'm stuck since I can only get the function to return the value of the Z in Zelle (which is supposed to be 26 here). I've pasted what I have so far below:

```
def get_numeric_value(string):
    numerals = []
    for character in string:
        if character.isupper():
            return ord(character) - 64
        elif character.islower():
            return ord(character) - 96
        return numerals
    addition = sum(numerals)
    return addition
```

I was thinking I would probably have to use `sum()` at *some* point, but I think the issue is more that I'm not getting all of the letters returned to the numerals list. How can I get it so the code will add up and return all the letters? I've been trying to think something up for an hour but I'm stumped.

Comment: What do you think `return` does?

Comment: `sum(to_numerical(c) for c in string)`?

Comment: @Julien From what I understand the return statement basically ends a function and sends the result back to the caller. More so I just learned to use it in conjunction with the accumulator pattern so I might not completely have the right idea.

Comment: exactly in _ends_ the function. So you are here only returning the value of the first character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just use a sum variable and add to it each character value and then return that sum:

```
def get_numeric_value(string):
    numerals = []
    sum = 0
    for character in string:
        if character.isupper():
            sum += ord(character) - 64
        elif character.islower():
            sum += ord(character) - 96
    return sum
```

Comment: I don't know how I didn't think about using a sum variable lol thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using `return` multiple times, each time the program reaches a `return` it stops the function and returns the specified value.

In your case the first letter fulfills one of the conditionals (specifically `character.isupper()`, returns the value of the letter and the program ends.

I think you wanted to use the `.append()` method, this method allows you to add elements to a list, leaving something like this:

```
def get_numeric_value(string):
    numerals = []
    for character in string:
        if character.isupper():
            numerals.append(ord(character) - 64)
        elif character.islower():
            numerals.append(ord(character) - 96)

    addition = sum(numerals)
    return addition
```

You can also use the to_numeric function you declared earlier, giving a much cleaner result (in my opinion).

```
def get_numeric_value(string):
    numerals = []
    for character in string:
        numerals.append(to_numerical(character))

    addition = sum(numerals)
    return addition
```

If you want it to be just one line you can use something called list comprehension, though you sacrifice some readability.

```
def get_numeric_value(string):
    return sum([to_numerical(character) for character in string])
```

Answer (score 0):

This one line answer should work as well:

```py
def get_numeric_value(string):
    return sum(ord(character) - (64 if character.isupper() else 96) for character in string if character.isalpha())
```

Answer (score 0):

why not just first lowecase the string to get rid of all the if-else blocks?
since all the characters are now lowercase we can use this function:

```
def get_numeric_value(string:str) -> int:
    return sum([ord(c) - 96 for c in string.lower() if c.isalpha()])
```